# NHibernate Querying by UTC date fields

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am trying to figure out how write a query in NHibernate so that the returned results are for a specific date from the users specific timezone. Currently all dates in the system are stored in UTC format and I store the time zone id with the currently logged in user. We were able to query in sql by converting the UTC date to the date of the users timezone with sql queries. Now we are converting over to using NHibernate. The code below is what I am trying to accomplish but NHibernate throws a NotSupportedException on "System.DateTime Add(System.TimeSpan)", also not sure if this matters but I am going after a MySQL database server.

```
    var readings = 
           session.Query<EnergyReading>()
          .Where(x => x.TimeStamp.Add(usersTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset).Date == usersTime.Date && x.DeviceId == deviceId);
```

**SOLUTION**

Based on degorolls suggestion I came up with the following which worked in my situation.

```
        var usersTime = Utility.GetCurrrentUsersDateTime();
        var afterDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(usersTime.Date);
        var beforeDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(usersTime.Date.AddDays(1));

        var energyReadingsList = context.Session.Query<EnergyReading>()
            .Where(x => x.TimeStamp > afterDate && x.TimeStamp < beforeDate)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeStamp)
            .ToList();
        Utility.ConvertEnergyReadingDatesToUsersTimeZone(energyReadingsList);
```

Comment: What is the query that this code produces. Also, what is does your `mysql` table look like?

Comment: Why not do the timezone adjustment outside the query? This would seem preferably anyway to avoid work at the database anyway.

Comment: shanabus - the table structure is very simple. contains three columns: (Id - VARCHAR(40)) (Energy - FLOAT) (TimeStamp - DATETIME)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var usersTimeUTC = usersTime.Date.Add(-usersTimeZone.BaseutcOffset);

var readings = 
           session.Query<EnergyReading>()
          .Where(x => x.TimeStamp == usersTimeUTC && x.DeviceId == deviceId);
```

**UPDATE:**

To adjust to match full day of users time zone:

```
// You might want to do adjust lines below to do a more precise adjustment based 
// on the actual date to properly account for daylight savings.
var usersTimeUTCStart = usersTime.Date.Add(-usersTimeZone.BaseUtcOffset);
var usersTimeUTCEnd = usersTimeUTCStart.AddHours(24);

    var readings = 
               session.Query<EnergyReading>()
              .Where(x => x.TimeStamp >= usersTimeUTCStart && 
                   x.TimeStamp < usersTimeUTCEnd && 
                   x.DeviceId == deviceId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay degorolls. But I messed up in my example of what I am trying to accomplish. What I need is to be able to query all the records for a given Date (year,month,day) of the users timezone.If I convert the users time to utc wouldnt I just get all the records for that particular UTC date?

Comment: QueryOver only offers very simple boolean logic via the where operators. It's ability to convert .Net expressions to SQL is very limited.